# Detect authentication attempts from ssh/console from an application for linux

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, console

There is a task to detect successful and unsuccessful login attempts from a linux C++ application. 
What is the best way to do it?

I've only found 2 ways: 
1) Check /var/logs/secure by timeout
2) Use inotify on /var/logs/secure

But there is an issue, that two or more unsuccessful login attemts in /var/logs/secure look like "PAM 2 more authentication failures" and this string is not appeared in a moment of unsuccessful login.

Comment: You may have better luck asking on http://serverfault.com. The fact that you're writing a program isn't very important here; the real question is where the information that you need would come from.

Comment: You can parse /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/btmp files. Something like "last" and "lastb" commands does. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093218/parsing-wtmp-logs-with-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a decent system, `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/btmp` are a best locations to check. Glibc provide functions to make its access easier: `getutxent`, `getutxid`, `getutxline`, etc...

Also check behaviour of `utmpdump -f /var/log/wtmp`, it very close of what you want (decode wtmp and follow new events).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.  It's actually much simpler:

1) Open the file

2) call `read()` *in non-blocking mode* over and over to read the data.

3) If you get `-EWOULDBLOCK`, then do a  `select()`. If data is ready to read, go back to step 2.

4) If the select times out (let's say 1 second timeout), check if the file has been rotated. (Simple way: Check the `ctime` on the new file. But there's probably a better way. Take a look at `tail -F` sources..)  If a new file has been created, call `close()` and go to 1. Otherwise, go to 3.

Also, take a look at [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).